# C - How to check if code is making efficient cache usage?

Tags: performance, caching, optimization, paging

I have an application which processes huge amount of data every 50ms. There are many structures which are used in tight nested loops. **I want to know if the code is making efficient use of cache.**

*I have also made effort to search here regarding this* and also got many good suggestions for best practices. But my issue is I don't have any tools to do this job.

I do know some basics about how structures have to be declared,loop unrolling etc.

I need something that can point out where I can optimize the code for better cache efficiency.

Also please suggest if any free tools are available for this.

*Environment data-
   Processor: MPC8610,
   Compiler: Windriver,
   Language: C*

Comment: Have you looked into profiling tools such as `gprof` and `valgrind`, the latter using the option `-tool=cachegrind`, which should give you an idea about hot spots and cache miss rate

Comment: Googled a bit on valgrind after you suggested. Looks like I will get into tutorials of that and check how I can apply that.Thanks.

Comment: another thing would be to see what performance counters are available on your architecture; there are also `pintool` for dynamic instrumentation (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) and `oprofile` (http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/); I assume your OS is linux- or unix-based